# How does WhenAll works with Tasks

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, parallel-processing

I have the following code inside my asp.net console application, to call a method named `gettingCustomerInfo` in parallel of 20 requests, as follow:

```cs
class Program
{
    static SemaphoreSlim throttler = new SemaphoreSlim(initialCount: 20);
    private static async Task<ScanInfo> gettingCustomerInfo(string website,
        string phone, long companyId)
    {
        await throttler.WaitAsync();
        ScanInfo si = new ScanInfo() { companyId = companyId };
        try
        {
            //code goes here...
        }
        finally
        {
            throttler.Release();
        }
    }

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool hasmore = true;
        string offset = string.Empty;
        bool first = true;

        try
        {
            while (hasmore || first)
            {
                Marketing ipfd = new Marketing();
                first = false;
                try
                {
                    // call the PM API to get the account id 
                    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
                    {
                        wc.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                        string url = "https://api.hubapi.com/companies/v2/companies/" +
                            "paged?hapikey=******properties=website" +
                            "&properties=mse_scan&properties=phone" +
                            "&limit=" + 100 + "&offset=" + offset;
                        string tempurl = url.Trim();
                        var json = wc.DownloadString(tempurl);
                        ipfd = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Marketing>(json);
                        int rrr = ipfd.companies.Count();
                        offset = ipfd.offset;
                        hasmore = ipfd.hasmore;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {

                }
                var tasks = ipfd.companies
                    .Select(c => Task.Run(() => gettingCustomerInfo
                        (
                            c.properties.website.value,
                            (
                                c.properties.phone != null &&
                                    !String.IsNullOrEmpty(c.properties.phone.value) ?
                                        c.properties.phone.value : null
                            ),
                            c.companyId
                        )
                    ));
                var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Now I got lost of how the logic and the flow of my code will run? Now inside the API call I am getting 100 items, then inside the `gettingCustomerInfo` I have defined a `SemaphoreSlim = 20`. but I am not sure how the flow of my code will be? Can anyone advice?

**Edit-1**

now i added the following inside my `gettingCustomerInfo` method:-

```
private static async Task<ScanInfo> gettingCustomerInfo(string website,string phone, long compnayId)
         {
            
            Console.WriteLine("a");
            await throttler.WaitAsync();
            ScanInfo si = new ScanInfo() { companyId = compnayId };
           
            Console.WriteLine("b");
```

and i got this pattern:-

```
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
b
b
a
b
a
b
b
b
a
b
a
b
b
a
b
b
b
a
b
a
b
a
b
a
b
a
b
```

Comment: why not run the debugger and step through the code to see the execution?

Comment: @LarryBud unfortunately, with possibly a lot of threads active, debugging may be a challenge because the debugger keeps skipping to another active thread

Comment: @LarryBud i tried to do so but i got lost on how the flow will run

Comment: I think that the code in your question has some noise that is unrelated to what you are asking, and could be removed. But after Stephen Cleary's answer it may not matter much. I don't think that anyone has a better answer to offer. :-)

Answer (score 4):

> now inside the api call i am getting 100 items, then inside the gettingCustomerInfo i have defined a SemaphoreSlim = 20. but i am not sure how the flow of my code will be?

So `companies` has 100 items, and those items are each `Select`ed into tasks.

When this code calls `Task.WhenAll`, all 100 tasks are created, and `gettingCustomerInfo` is invoked 100 times.

The first 20 calls to `await throttler.WaitAsync` will complete immediately and continue executing, running `//code goes here`. As each one completes, it will call `Release`, which completes one of the 80 calls waiting at `await throttler.WaitAsync`.

Eventually, all 100 calls will finish running `//code goes here` (no more than 20 at a time), and then the `await Task.WhenAll` completes.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. so what does ` static SemaphoreSlim throttler = new SemaphoreSlim(initialCount: 20);` mean? does it mean that it will ensure that no more than 20 active threads will be running at one? if the answer is yes then how it performs this?

Comment: can you please check my edit-1 seems the 100 tasks will not be called at once

Comment: @JohnJohn: Yes, it ensures that no more than 20 can run at once. It does this by keeping a list of waiting tasks.
The 100 tasks do not all start at once because you're starting them on thread pool threads, and the thread pool has a limited injection rate.